# Using Weights to Create a Ranking where the Weights can be negative

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, average, standard-deviation

I've got a question that's a variation of this one:
[How to weight three different variables to create a ranking](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/760939/how-to-weight-three-different-variables-to-create-a-ranking)

I'm starting a new question because of the age of the other question.  The difference is that in my situation, I want to allow the *weights* to be negative.  In the other question, an answer very helpfully describes how to handle the case where the *scores* can be negative, but when the weights are negative, the math does not work out.

I expect that having a negative score in a category with a negative weight contributes to having a **higher** overall score, and having a higher positive score in a category with a negative weight would be contribute to having a **lower** overall score... Perhaps even a negative score.

One of the things with which I'm struggling, is the case where two weights are given, for example, 1 and -1.  When dividing by the sum of the scores, you end up dividing by 0.  What is the proper way to deal with this?

**EDIT:**
Here's what worked:  Transfer the sign of the weight to the value, and then treat the weight as if it were positive.  So, if value is positive, and then weight is negative, the scored value is negative.  If the value is negative, and the weight is negative, the scored value is positive (which makes sense if you have a low value in something with a negative weight).  When dividing by the sum of all the weights, you have to divide by the sum of the absolute value of the weights, so that in the case of the weights being +1 and -1 and dividing by zero, instead, you divide by +2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you deal with the absolute values for the weights then it's equivalent to having the score negative. Say you have scores $s_{+,-}$ with weights $w_{+,-}$, with $w_-<0<w_+$. Then $$\frac{w_+s_++w_-s_-}{|w_+|+|w_-|}=\frac{|w_+|s_++|w_-|(-s_-)}{|w_+|+|w_-|}$$ 
Not sure if negative weight make sense.

Comment: They make sense in that sometimes a low value is better than a high one. All of the values are Z-Scores (subtract the average, divide by the standard deviation), which are pretty much in the range of -3 to 3.  I want a way to specify that LOW scores are better than high ones.

But what you said goes along with my current approach...  I'm multiplying the score by the sign of the weight, and then just dealing with the absolute value of the weights.  This makes the high scores as if they were low, and the low scores as if they were high.

Comment: You can still use positive weights. Think something like $1/|w|$

Comment: And, it gets around the case where the two weights are 1 and -1 and dividing by their sum is not allowed...  Instead, I divide by 2, so each weight contributes half, but the signs are flipped for the negative weights.

Comment: You need a concrete example in order to come up with a meaningful weight.

Comment: Consider the example the linked question.  The user gets to pick weights (say 0-1) for 3 different categories.  Now let's say I wanted to give the user the option to specify they want a school with a HIGH cost or a LOW graduation rate.  Yes, I could do 1/N and change the way the scores are defined, but that would apply to ALL situations, and wouldn't give the option of going low or high.

So, given that, will my approach work?

Comment: For the example linked, just replace the value with (maximum allowed-value)

Comment: Although your answer didn't end up being what I needed, you were the only one who attempted to answer my question, and you said "equivalent to having the score negative", which is correct and moving the negative sign from the weight to the score ended up being the solution, so I'm accepting your answer.  Thank you for your help!